# Could I use breakpoints list set in Visual Studio in windbg?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windbg

As you know Visual Studio is an IDE and windbg is just a debugger.

I always browser code in visual studio and copy the method name then paste to windbg to debug.

I wonder could I set breakpoints in vs and then start windbg and it'll use the bp list in vs?

Comment: You do know Visual Studio has a debugger, right?

Comment: But windbg is much faster, sometimes I want to use windbg to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, the problem is that when the bp is hit it raises an exception that the debugger quietly grabs and compares to it's list of known breakpoints. While it might be possible to have both debuggers attached, it would probably be a toss up of who got the exception first, also attaching two debuggers to the same process can cause odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set breakpoints from both Visual studio and WinDbg, there can only be one debugger that is attached invasively.

You can attach invasively with Visual Studio and attach non-invasively with WinDbg but both cannot attach invasively.

Similarly if you attach invasively with WinDbg you cannot attach invasively with VS, the option will be greyed out for your exe.